# reverse string using recursion javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

In this program I've tried to check whether the given input is string or not, if not string means console out the input value, else reverse the string using the recursion function.. When I provide the `typeof` in code, I got an error in first line, without it it runs correctly...

```
function reverseString(str) {
  if (typeof str !== "string"){
    return str;
  }
  else{
   return reverseString(str.substr(1)) + str.charAt(0);
 }
}
console.log(reverseString("good"));
```

Comment: str is always a string, even when empty, so the recursive function never finishes, hence call stack exceeded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function reverseString(str) {
  if (typeof str !== "string") {
    return str;
  }

  // you must add this line. rest of the code is fine
  if (!str.length) return str; // this terminates the recursion when it reaches the end

  return reverseString(str.substring(1)) + str.charAt(0);
}

console.log(reverseString("!detseT"));
```

Comment: Avoid using substr 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use this directly?

```js
function reverseString(str) {
  if (typeof str !== "string"){
    return str;
  }
  else{
   return str.split('').reverse().join('');
 }
}
console.log(reverseString("good"));
```

You split your string in an array of characters, you reverse  it and you join it.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the string and use `charAt(str.length - 1)` to get the element from string. then `str.slice(0, str.length - 1` will remove the last character from the string and call the same recursive function

```js
function reverseString(str, finalStr) {
  if (!finalStr) {
    finalStr = '';
  }
  if (str.length === 0) {
    finalStr += str;
    return finalStr
  } else {
    finalStr += str.charAt(str.length - 1);
    return reverseString(str.slice(0, str.length - 1), finalStr)
  }

}

console.log(reverseString("good"));
```